# Return a Status Code 304 in Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return a 304 Not Modified status code in my ASP.Net Core application when a file is accessed via my middleware.

I try setting the HTTP Status Code and sending the response back like so:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 304;
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Not Modified");
```

But I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException occurred   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=Write to non-body 304 response.
>   Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.HandleNonBodyResponseWrite()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.d__183.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>          at Adapt.REST.ServeStaticFilesMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext() in
>   C:\AdaptSource\Xivic\Adapt.Services\ServeStaticFilesMiddleware.cs:line
>   113   InnerException:

So obviously I can't use WriteAsync or SendFileAsync because they both send a response that contains a body.

How do I send a 304 back to the client without a body?

Comment: If you call WriteAsync with empty string the error will not show up: `await context.Response.WriteAsync("");`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply doing nothing after setting the status code causes the intended functionality.

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 304;
return;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response :). It helped me to fix the issue.